# Check if an element belongs to a list associated with key in dictionary without for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

**Problem formulation :**

Check if an element belongs to a list of values associated to a key in a dictionary and returns the indices of keys.

Each key of the dictionary is associated with a list of values. For instance :

```
498 : {1299,45,78}
875 :{45,104,200,300,456}
```

The number of **keys** in the dictionary is **30,000**

elements = [45,65,65,...,104,..., 875] # Elements is composed of about **900,000**  integer values

**What the algorithm do ?**

Looks for each element in the dictionary and returns the indices of the keys where it belongs to.

For instance :

**45** belongs to **keys** number **498** and **875**

**What l have tried ?**

```
for elt in elements:
        Keys_indices_elt = [key for key, list in dictionary.items() if elt in list]
```

**What is the problem ?**

The use of nested loops is not efficient and it takes about 9 hours to return the mapping between 30,000 keys and 900,000 elements.

Is there any efficient way to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to build a reverse index prior to processing the loop.

It should look something like this:

```
{
    1299: {498},
    45: {498, 875},
    78: {498},
    104: {875},
    # etc.
}
```

To build it, you simply iterate through your dictionary and use the values in your dictionary as keys in your reverse index. Something like this:

```
rev_idx = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for e in v:
        if e in rev_idx:
            rev_idx[e].add(k)
        else:
            rev_idx[e] = {k}
```

This will of course use some memory and processing time, but then you will be able to get an answer for each of 900,000 elements almost instantaneously. I would expect that with this approach, your program would run for about two seconds instead of 9 hours.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However l am not sure that it's clear for me and how to build this dictionary by reversing the indices of keys and values

Comment: The processing time to build a reverse index is of order of  seconds/minutes/hours ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, but really it's up to you to find out how to do it. The processing time to build the reverse index is included in my estimate.